# is there any AWS handler for micronaut app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, micronaut

I am trying to deploy my application to `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` and get stuck on database connection.

I already create `DB Instance`, `DB Cluster` and i already setting up the `Environment's variable` like this.

[image]

this is my `application.yml`

```
datasources:
    default:
        url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_authentication?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false`}
        username: ${JDBC_USER:root}
        password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:root}
        driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}
```

I'm sure that my database was exist.

[image]

this is my latest log.

```
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:194)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1329)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1902)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1623)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1603)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:896)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:973)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateSessionFactoryBuilderDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:197)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1329)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1902)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1623)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1603)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:896)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:973)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateSessionFactoryDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:197)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1329)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1902)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1533)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1049)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry]

Message: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) --> MetadataSources.hibernateMetadataSources(JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration,[StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry]) --> StandardServiceRegistry.hibernateStandardServiceRegistry(String dataSourceName,[DataSource dataSource])
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1343)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1902)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1623)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1603)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:896)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:973)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Comment: Does that configuration you posted reflect the actual indentation? Is `datasources` on the same level as `default` ?

Comment: @JamesKleeh yes, actual configuration, and ofcourse at the same level.

Comment: Then that isn't correct. I see you've edited it so `default` is now underneath `datasources`. I assume that it now accurately represents your config. I would make sure you have any network security settings setup correctly in AWS to allow you to connect

Comment: @JamesKleeh it means my edited post already correct, right? i still trying to find what went wrong with my configuration

Comment: @user2809386 try to hide passwords when posting :-)